# MarkLogic/Python query only searches for one file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, marklogic, marklogic-8

fetching data from Marklogic database but code is searching only for one file. Is there any other way to achieve the objective

```
import `http`.`client`

`conn` = `http`.`client`.`HTTPConnection`("127.0.0.1:8040")

headers = {
    'authorization': "Digest `username`=\"root\", realm=\"public\", nonce=\"\", `uri`=\"/v1/documents?`uri`=/scripts/test_insert_2.`json`\", response=\"f5d58bcbccc9119fbf71f851ac4e90f0\", opaque=\"\"",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "52c1f629-5bb9-e16c-5693-16d8d6001e2d"
    }

`conn`.`request`("GET", "/v1/documents?`uri`=%2Fscripts%2Ftest_insert_2.`json`", headers=headers)

res = `conn`.`getresponse`()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def searchkeyword(self, keyword):
    try:
        self.querystring = {"q": keyword}
        url = self.baseUri + "/search"
        self.header = {'Accept': "application/json"}
        resp = requests.get(url, auth=self.auth, params=self.querystring, headers=self.header)
        result = json.loads(resp.content)
        res = []
        fres = []
        for uri in result['results']:
            x = uri['uri']
            if x.__contains__(self.collection):
                res.append(x)
        for x in res:
            data = x.split('/')
            output = self.FetchData(data[2])
            fres.append(output)
        return fres
    except requests.HTTPError:
        raise RuntimeError('HTTPError occurred while fetching data from file on MarkLogic server')
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        raise RuntimeError('ConnectionError occurred while fetching data from file on MarkLogic server')
```

Comment: This function helps me in finding specific keyword in MarkLogic DB.

Comment: This will help you to get the document from a particular collection.

Answer (score 2):

You code is not searching, it is explicitly asking for a single document.

To retrieve more than one document at a time, you would include the URI in the request against the `/documents` end point:

URL:

```
http://host:port/version/documents?uri=uri-1&uri=uri-2&...
```

curl:

```
$ curl --anyauth --user user:password -X GET -i \
  -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \
  'http://host:port/LATEST/documents?uri=uri-1&uri=uri-2'
```

If you want to return more than one, you need to use `\search` REST end point to allow searching across documents.  More information is found in the [Query Features section](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search) and the [Reading and Writing Multiple Documents section](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk) of the [REST Application Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev)